# Is it possible to create visual elements in PyQt6?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, pyqt6

As my code is quite long and with a lot of nested layouts I won't put it in here but I essentially have a QHBoxLayout which I want to have a different background colour as the others. I First thought about changing the stylesheet but I quickly learned that the layout is not affected by that as it apparently is not a visual element. Hence my Question: How do I create simple (geometric) elements? Is it even possible to just have a colored box in the background and some lables and pictures in the foreground?

I tried just using a big QTextEdit block and colouring this with the StyleSheet but this didn't get me the results I hoped for as It'd be hard to align the text the way I want it to be and add pictures.

Comment: That depends on your needs. What would be the purpose of those shapes? Would they interact each other? Is the user expected to interact with them? Your description is quite vague, but it's possible that you may need to use the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), or at least QPainter capabilities.

Comment: It's quite simple which is why it probably appears to be vague - I essentially just want my QHBoxLayout to have a different background colour. No interaction needed, just multiple differently coloured boxes.

Comment: Then use a QWidget as container for the widgets you want to add and set a style sheet for it [using proper selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), and add that QWidget instead of the nested layout. Don't use widgets for wrong purposes: the purpose of QTextEdit is to show text, not to change the look of the program.